# Respostas que na verdade são perguntas para esclarecer a pergunta

Tags: debate, suporte

Tenho visto muitas perguntas que estão sendo respondidas por perguntas. Isto é, para obter mais informação sobre a pergunta, tirar dúvidas, etc., (coisa que deveria ser feita nos comentários), os usuários estão respondendo a pergunta.

Qual deve ser nossa atitude neste caso? Existe alguma sugestão de o que deve ser feito?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Todos os casos que vi era gente com pouca reputação. Sem poder postar comentários, postavam respostas. Em todos os casos, sinalizei o post com "não é uma resposta" - a solução embarcada em todos os sites do Stack Exchange para esse tipo de problema.

Comment: Também é aconselhável deixar um comentário explicando o uso correto da área de respostas. Temos sugestões de alguns comentários padronizados aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/707

Comment: A questão de usuários novos não poderem comentar é levantada constantemente, mas [sempre se mantém](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/842/12). Marcar como "não é uma resposta" e deixar o comentário explicando é realmente a melhor saída.